# nginx forward traffic contitionally

Tags: nginx

An nginx configuration does reverse proxy fine, but when This Meteor app starts using a package named meteorhacks:cluster, the browser console gives errors in the first image.
The error went away when I removed the SSL support in the nginx config file. like so:

Looking at the error, and considering the [nginx variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) $request_uri. Is it the right way (to fix this) to place a condition so that when a certain url is requested, the reverse proxy is bypassed?

If so, what and how?

```
# Redirect 'www' addresses to the non-www version with SSL.
server {                                                   
  listen 80;                                               
  server_name www.PLACEHOLDER_VHOST;                       
#  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;          //<------- commented out         
  return 301 http://$host$request_uri;            //<------- replaced with this         
}                                                          


  # Support for SSL
  #  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {          //<------- commented out
  #    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;          //<------- commented out
  #  }                                                //<------- commented out
```

[image]